# How can I get the total CPU usage of a Linux machine with 1 or n CPU cores?

Tags: cpu-usage

I am currently using the below method to extract CPU usage idle value from top command and subtracting the value from 100. Is this method correct and is there a better way to achieve the same.

Also, my linux VM is a stripped down version and has only few basic tools like `top`. Installing other tools is not an option as the package manager is also removed.

```
CPU_IDLE="$(top -bn2 | grep -F '%Cpu' | tail -n 4 | gawk '{print $8 $9}' | tr -s '\n\:\,[:alpha:]' ' '| gawk '{print $2}'),"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method alright.

But, you could use [`mpstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mpstat) to get more details.

It is included in [sysstat](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/admin/sysstat) package, and if you don't have it installed...

On CentOS / RHEL:

```
sudo yum install sysstat
```

On Ubuntu / Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

Use bellow command if you don't have any permission to install a package

```
grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage "%"}'
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that my linux VM is a stripped down version and has only few basic tools like top. Installing other tools is not an option as the package manager is also removed.

Comment: You could extract a `deb` package and copy files manually, or compile from source code.

Comment: Hey Rakib, looks like the command is not giving actual values. Yesterday ,I ran a script to log the CPU usage for almost 8 hours and I plotted a graph from the datapoints. However, it didn't match to the CPU history shown on my hyper visor for this linux VM.